# How to take the input for a simple linear search function in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a simple array of numbers, from which I will check if a particular integer is found. I was able to make the array of 10 numbers with this code:

```
int main(void) 
{

int values[ 10 ]; 
int g;

for (g = 0; g < 10; g++ ) {
  values[ g ] = g + 10; /* set element at location i to i + 10 */
  printf("%i", values[g]);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

I then hoped to perform a linear search of the array with this code:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int m)
{
   // TODO: implement a searching algorithm
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    if ( value == values[i])
    return true;
}
  return false;
}
```

However, I have been struggling in finding where I can actually input the integer value that I want to search for. I thought to simply place

```
 value = get_int();
```

within or following the main function.However, both situations return errors. How can I proceed?

Comment: the `main()` function is missing a few needed statements.  1) declare a variable hold the  value 2) call some I/O function, like `scanf()`, to input the value from the user (be sure to check for I/O errors) 3) call the 'search()` function with the needed parameters.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scanf` to read an input from the user.
[Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)